# Is this unqualified lookup in c++?

Tags: c++, lookup

```
    #include <iostream>
    namespace X
    {
        int k  = 8;
    }
    int main()
    {
        using namespace X;
        int  k = 0;


        std::cout << k;


        return 0;
    }
```

I am struggling to understand the difference between qualified and unqualified lookup, and how they deal with using namespace ; phrases

For now, I would like to make clear ?Here k  causes qualified lookup right?

Comment: No, it's `std::cout` that's causing the qualified lookup for the `<<` operator defined in the `std` namespace.

Comment: No no I am taking about looking up the variable k

Comment: The difference between qualified and unqualified lookup depends on the name to be looked up. Here, that's `k` in `std::cout`. The using-directive doesn't matter **yet**; the compiler first has to decide that it's an unqualified lookup. Only then does the `using` matter. Because of this, `using` cannot affect the choice of lookup type.

Answer (score 3):

It is [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> For an unqualified name, **that is a name that does not appear to the
>   right of a scope resolution operator ::**, name lookup examines the
>   scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of
>   any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are
>   examined.

as `k` does not appear to the right of a scope resolution operator.

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan when one edits the question answers often become invalid. That's not how SO works.

Comment: Look I am new to the site, I didn't realise that, but so whatever

Comment: in the new code, if it is unqualified lookup why isn't it treating using namespace as a declaration (as it usually does)

Comment: Instead  it prints 0

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan how name lookup works is another question. I suggest you post another question for that if you want. The original question was answered: it is unqualified name lookup.

Comment: @HovhannesVardanyan I have done so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359856/unqualified-name-lookup-why-local-declaration-hides-declaration-from-using-dire