# Unqualified name lookup: Why local declaration hides declaration from using directive

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, name-lookup

Consider this code:

```
namespace A
{
   int i = 24;
}

namespace B
{
    using namespace A;
    int i = 11;

    int k = i; // finds B::i, no ambiguity
}
```

And [basic.lookup.unqual.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#2):

> §6.4.1 Unqualified name lookup [basic.lookup.unqual]
>
> 2. The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see
>      [namespace.udir]. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules
>      described in [basic.lookup.unqual], the declarations from the
>      namespace nominated by the using-directive are considered members of
>      that enclosing namespace.

For me the standard says pretty clear that for the purpose of unqualified name lookup (the `i` in `int k = i`) the declaration of `i` from `A` is considered member of `B` so `i` should be ambiguous in `int k = i`, however both `gcc` and `clang` [compile](https://godbolt.org/g/vCE39W) and resolve `i` to the local `B::i`. I have searched the standard ([basic.scope.hiding](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding) and [namespace.udir](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir)) and did not find an exception or a  rule to contradict the above one. I have found that for qualified name lookup, but not for unqualified name lookup.

Why is `i` unambiguous?

Comment: this a continuation to a question from another user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359294/is-this-unqualified-lookup-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is 10.3.4/2 "During unqualified name lookup, the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace."

The nominated namespace is A, the using directive is in B, and the smallest (in fact only) common namespace is the global namespace. Thus `i` appears as if declared in the global namespace, and is hidden by `B::i`.