# using directive and function overloading in a namespace

Tags: c++

The compiler doesn't see the function `std::to_string`, despite the using directive. Why is that?

```
#include <string>
namespace MySpace
{
    using namespace std;

    struct X
    {
        int n;
    };

    string to_string(X x)
    {
        return to_string(x.n);//Error here
    }
}
```

All works fine if I move the stuff out of `MySpace` to the global namespace, or if I explicitly add `using std::to_string;` declaration into `MySpace`.

Comment: what is the error? Btw to me this is a perfect example of why `using namespace` isnt nice. Why do you insist on having two meanings for `to_string` in one scope?

Comment: `std::to_string(x.n);`

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359856/unqualified-name-lookup-why-local-declaration-hides-declaration-from-using-dire). There `A` takes the place of `std` and `i` takes the place of `to_string`.

Comment: @user463035818 to make the compiler to choose suitable one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is truly arcane, and has to do with the way both `using` directive and overload resolution works.

First, let's look at the `using` directive. When you inject namespace with it within another namespace, it works by actually injecting the namespace into

> the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the
>   using-directive and namespace [being used]. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives).

In your case, such namespace would be global namespace, is it would be the only one encompassing the `std` and `My Space`. The effect of it would be that names, defined in namespace `std` would behave as if they are defined in global namespace.

Let's look at overload resolution now. When the function is looked up by the name, the name is first searched in local namespace, and if not found, search continues in surrounding namespace, then one level up... - until the name(s) is(are) found, or we reach global namespace. Once at least one name is found, search stops there, and a qualified overload is chosen from the set of names using overload rules. In your case, this search immediately yields a single name - `to_string` - which is than rejected, as it does not accept `int` argument (it only accepts `X`).

On the other hand, when you do not use `MySpace`, names from `std` are put in the global namespace as well, but your own `to_string` exists in global namespace now. As a result, multiple `to_string` versions are found in global namespace, including yours, and the proper one `to_string(int)` is than selected based on the argument type.

Answer (score 6):

It's because of this **[namespace.udir]**:

> During unqualified name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear
>   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the
>   nominated namespace.

So `using namespace std;` for the purposes of *unqualified* name lookup in effect brings names into *the global namespace*, not into `MySpace`. Declarations in `MySpace` hide declarations from `namespace std` introduced in this manner.

If you move everything into the global namespace, it starts to work because your own `to_string` and `std::to_string` now appear in the same namespace, as far as unqualified lookup is concerned.

Comment: In this case this is not true: "So using `namespace std;` in effect brings names into the global namespace":, proof: https://wandbox.org/permlink/D89pEfGouLYm57MC

Comment: @MarekR you are not doing it correctly. Read the link from my answer, especially `...From the point of view of **unqualified name lookup of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope** in which it appears`

Comment: @MarekR this of course only applies to unqualified name lookup. Added clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is because of wrong usage, you are not calling `std::to_string` inside of definition of `MySpace::to_string`. So, it works fine in the namespace `MySpace` too, just shadows `to_string` function which declered in `std` namespace.

The following code compiles fine:

```
namespace MySpace
{
    using namespace std;

    struct X
    {
        int n;
    };

    string to_string(X x)
    {
        return std::to_string(x.n); // No error anymore here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer why it works outside of namespace.

Comment: No, it was not @SergeyA. Because my approach was not correct. I edited my answer and I think that this answer is the correct one. Fully fully qualified namespace solves the problem

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't address the difference between using `MySpace` and not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is already specified that using `std::` solves the problem at end of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Best approach is to import specific functions into a name space.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace MySpace
{
    using std::to_string;

    struct X
    {
        int n;
    };

    std::string to_string(const X &x)
    {
        return to_string(x.n);
    }
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/BD520ZCACv9hwF4q

Comment: This doesn't really answer why the OP's code fails to compile.

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: the "best appraoch" ? really? what about stop being lazy and type `std::` instead of `using`?